# Meteor js and jspdf or any PDF library returning Buffer not defined

Tags: reactjs, meteor, pdfkit, pdfmake, pdf.js

Anytime I add a pdf lib. on my Meteor/React app, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined at util.js`. I've tried all the proposed methods: `init.js`, `meteor npm i --save buffer`,

```
import Buffer from 'buffer';

if (typeof this.Buffer === 'undefined') {
  this.Buffer = Buffer.Buffer;
}
```

all of these with no solution. I'm using `Meteor 1.8.0.2`. This is very annoying.

Comment: Is `util.js` a file from the PDF lib or your code? Can you please link the file, if external, or post the Buffer related code if it's yours?

Comment: The file is from pdfjs (pdfjs/lib/util) here is the related code blcoc

`exports.toArrayBuffer = function(b) {
  if (b instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    return b
  } else {
    return b.buffer.slice(b.byteOffset, b.byteOffset + b.byteLength)
  }
}`

Comment: Did you build it own your own using gulp (as in the docs) or installed an npm package (which one)?

Comment: I used npm (meteor npm install --save pdfjs).

Comment: does it help to replace the global buffer: `global.Buffer = Buffer.Buffer` ?

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by:
1. install buffer -> `meteor npm install buffer`
2. Add the following lines of code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  const buffer = require("buffer");
  global.Buffer = buffer.Buffer;
}
```